# Finding total edit time for R files

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to determine how much time I have spent on a project, which has mainly been done in .R files.  I know the file.info function will extract metadata for me on that file, but since I have opened it several times over several days, I don't know how to use that information to determine total time editing.  Is there a function to find this information, or a way to go through the file system to find it?

Comment: No. There's no where that data would be stored. That's not something that's tracked in a file or by RStudio. You can only see when a file was created and when it was last modified. Even things like git only track changes, not time spent on a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: you could maintain a log file to which you write the following from your R script: start time, stop-time and R script file name.
You can add simple code in your script that would do this. You would then require a separate script that would analyse the logs and inform you about how much time was spent using the scipt. 
For a single user this would work.

Note: this catches script execution time and not the time spent on editing the files. The log would still have merit: you would have a record of when you were working on the script under the assumption that you run your scripts frequently when developing code.

How about using an old-fashioned time sheet for the purpose of recording development time? Tools such as [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) are very suitable for that purpose.

For example at the start of the script:

```
logFile <-file("log.txt")
writeLines(paste0("Scriptname start: ", Sys.time()), logFile)
close(logFile)
```

And at the end of the script:

```
logFile <-file("log.txt")
writeLines(paste0("Scriptname stop: ", Sys.time()), logFile)
close(logFile)
```